# Symfony FOS rest bundle not getting my json data from API urls

Tags: json, symfony, routes, fosrestbundle

I am trying to call this api : `http://localhost/api/columns {"tab":"client"}`

but I couldn't get that one value from the json format

I get this error from the browser : `{"code":404,"message":"No route found for \"GET \/api\/columns%20%7B%22tab%22:%22client%22%7D\""}`

And tihs from CURL : `{"code":400,"message":"Parameter \"tab\" of value \"NULL\" violated a constraint \"This value should not be null.\""}`

This is my fos_rest.yml file :

```
fos_rest:
routing_loader: false
body_listener: true
exception:
  enabled: true
param_fetcher_listener: force
view:
  view_response_listener: 'force'
  formats:
    json: true
format_listener:
  rules:
    - { path: '^/api', prefer_extension: false , priorities: [json], fallback_format: json}
```

routes.yml

```
dashboard:
  type: rest
  resource: App\Controller\DashboardController
  prefix : api
```

What I get from : `php bin/console debug:router` to check my routes :

```
get_columns                GET      ANY      ANY    /api/columns.{_format}
```

Comment: what? the url that matches your route is /api/columns.json.

Comment: How can i change it , its auto generated routing from the fos rest bundle